# use data attribute in animate function

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use the data attribute value in the jquery animate function in order to set speed of the animation depending on the data attribute value.

html

```
<li class="layer" data-depth="2"><img src="imgs/logo/zaincorp logo.png"></li>
<li class="layer" data-depth="4"><img src="imgs/logo/creative hands logo.png"></li>
<li class="layer" data-depth="6"><img src="imgs/logo/la logo.png"></li>
```

jquery

```
function slide(){
    layer.animate({
        'left': '+='+data('depth')*20+'px'
    },100, 'linear',function(){
        slide();
    });
}
slide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate the elements:

```
function slide() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.animate({
        'left': '+=' + $this.data('depth') * 20 + 'px'
    }, 100, 'linear', slide);
}

$('.layer').each(slide);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I have a doubt why we use $this instead directly using $(this).

Comment: Doing `$(this)` takes time because it creates a new jQuery object. So I create the object once and use it twice.